# Should I consider the quantity of each atom when estimating the relative lattice energies of two compounds?

Tags: energy

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_nf7JmB9iI), at 1:30, the presenter remarks that the charge of $\mathrm{Na}$ is $1^{+}$ and that the charge of $\mathrm{Cl}$ is $1^{-}$. Then, at 2:00, he remarks that the charge of $\mathrm{Fe}$ is $3^{+}$ and that the charge of $\mathrm{O}$ is $2^{-}$. Finally, he remarks that the result of substituting $3^{+}$ and $2^{-}$ for $q_1$ and $q_2$ in $ E_{\mathrm{latice}} =\frac{Kq_1q_2}{r}$ is six times the result of substituting $1^{+}$ and $1^{-}$ in the same equation. Hence he assumes that the value of $r$ is the same for both compounds, and concludes that the lattice energy of $\mathrm{Fe_2O_3}$ is six tiems greater than the lattice energy of $\mathrm{NaCl}$.

I thought that the fact that $\mathrm{Fe_2O_3}$ comprises more charged atoms than $\mathrm{NaCl}$ comprises would affect the differences between their lattice energies. Accordingly, I thought that the presenter should have multiplied the charge of $\mathrm{Fe}$ by $2$ and multiplied the charge of $\mathrm{O}$ by $3$, and then substituted those two products into $q_\mathrm{1}q_\mathrm{2}$ respectively? Evidently, I was wrong about that.

In estimating the relative lattice energies, should the estimator consider the number of each kind of atom in the compounds?

Comment: Experimentally some people found out before us that multiplying by the number of ions in one formula unit (i.e multiplying by 2 + 3 = 5) gave more accurate results. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapustinskii_equation In this case you have $\nu = 5$, $z_+ = 2$, $z_- = 3$, making the lattice energy a grand total of 30 times larger. (I have seen different forms of this equation, but they are all proportional to $\nu$.)

Comment: Sorry, make that 15 times larger, because $\ce{NaCl}$ has $\nu = 2$. A quick Google search shows that the lattice enthalpy of $\ce{Fe2O3}$ is around 14774 kJ/mol, whereas that of $\ce{NaCl}$ is 787 kJ/mol. 14774/787 = 18.77. Close enough, I guess, considering that we are ignoring changes in the ionic radii here.